# PHP - search in array and add attribute to original array if there is a positive result

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays - **$products** and **$userProducts** (this has to be done with two queries since I am searching for products based on the name, and there is another table where I store products which user wants to sell, and I want to show to the user that he already put this product for sale).

**$products array** looks like this:

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'product name',
    'synonim' => 'synonim'...

],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'product name 2',
    'synonim' => 'synonim'...

]....
```

and **$userProducts** looks like this:

```
[
    'product_id' => 1 
],
[
    'product_id' => 75
]
```

I want to add attribute to the **$products** array (or if there is a better way to do this, that can also work) `'userHasProduct' => true`, if **$userProducts** contains **product_id** which mathces with **id** from **$products** id. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why does it have to be two separate queries? Because it seems like a left join would solve your problem

Comment: Check this one http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @Erik - tried this, and I am not getting a result I want (I am not that proficient with MySQL, so it is possible that I don't have the knowledge to write the query I need).

Comment: @Sasha- I'd recommend asking a _new question_ and share the data structure, and the query you've tried, to get help writing this query.  And don't forget about the folks who are trying to help with this question below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreeing with @Erik that if you can amend your original query then this would probably be best solved in the database layer. If not, then you can use something like this:

```
$products = array_map(function ($product) use ($userProducts) {
  if (in_array($product['id'], array_column($userProducts, 'product_id'))) {
    $product['found_in_user_products'] = true;
  }

  return $product;
}, $products);
```

This will loop over each entry in your `$products` array, and compare the ID to the list in `$userProducts`. If it's found, then it sets the `found_in_user_products` key to true.

Working example: https://eval.in/858063

For reference, to solve this in SQL would probably look something like:

```
   Select p.id, p.name, p.synonim, count(up.product_id)
     From products p
Left Join user_products up On p.id = up.product_id
 Group By p.id, p.name, p.synonim
```

Although obviously without seeing your schema it's hard to say exactly

Comment: Nice! I always forget about `array_column` - worth noting that requires PHP 5.5+ (everyone should be on that, but alas many still are not)

Comment: Better move the `array_column` out of the loop, because the no reason to do the same task each time. (-;

Answer (score 1):

If a query `LEFT JOIN` truly won't solve the problem (which I believe it would, BTW), I would then recommend something like this:

```
// flatten the array
$ids = array_map( function( $row ) {
    return $row['product_id'];
}, $row );

// loop over products (by reference)
foreach( $products AS &$row ) {
    // if the product ID is in the user's IDs array, set flag
    if ( in_array($row['product_id'], $ids ) {
        $row['userHasProduct'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```